# No suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.Boolean] and content type [application/json]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

I am calling a rest endpoint in my code and the endpoint is returning a simple string "true" or "false". I have upgraded my spring boot to 2.4. The below code is now throwing an exception now.

```
 ResponseEntity<Boolean> status = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Boolean.class);
```

org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.Boolean] and content type [application/json]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:126) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1037) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1020) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]

How to resolve this issue?

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the `restTemplate` does not have suitable MessageConverters. By default `restTemplate` of Spring boot provides the message converters which can convert the Boolean response.

But, if you override the list of message converters for example like below -
`restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter()));`

Then, Spring boot will not be able to convert the message.

Just verify what are the message converters added to `restTemplate` instance that you are using and check whether `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is present or not. Or you can use your own custom message converter.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the response entity things just add as below.

```
Boolean  status = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Boolean.class);
```